# Type '{ id: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ id?: string; }'

Tags: jhipster

Based on [Matt Raible's article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/25/react-spring-boot-photo-gallery-pwa), I create an application with the same JHipster options other than authentication type and development database. With his JH entity file, I get the following errors

```
error  in /home/me/workspace/gallery/src/main/webapp/app/entities/album/album-delete-dialog.tsx

ERROR in /home/me/workspace/gallery/src/main/webapp/app/entities/album/album-delete-dialog.tsx(12,97):
TS2344: Type '{ id: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ id?: string; }'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It seems to me that there is an error in JHipster. I use the latest version, 5.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a breaking change introduced by one of the node dependencies which doesn't use fixed versions for their dependencies (a new release of `@types/react-router` requires a string instead of a number).  The latest release of JHipster has this fixed.

To solve it in your project, upgrade `generator-jhipster` and regenerate your entities.  If you prefer to fix it manually, fix all React components that extend `RouteComponentProps` to use a `string` prop for the `id` like [in this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/29b550cf023be8e7258bf33e502c635459b22c3d)

[JHipster Dev Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jhipster-dev/j5Y3TUfgqf4)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I run the upgrade command "yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster". The command runs properly without any error, but jhipster isn't upgraded for some reason.

Comment: You may have installed it with both `npm` and `yarn`, try removing it from both then installing with only one